# How to make a button write a file to sdcard?

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, overwrite, copying

In my app I want a button which when pressed copies a file stored in my apps raw folder to sdcard/Android/data... overwriting an existing file that is already there.

Here is what I have so far. The file in my raw folder is called `brawler.dat` for an example.

I'm not asking anyone to write the entire code, but that would be a bonus for sure.

I need mainly someone to point me in the right direction.

I can create buttons to go to URL's etc... but I'm ready for the next level, I feel.

main.xml

```
 rLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Overwrite File" />
```

FreelineActivity.java

```
     package my.freeline.conquest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FreelineActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following simple call the copyRawFile().For more details on storage refer to  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

```
    private void copyRawFile() {


                InputStream in = null;
                OutputStream out = null;
    String filename="myFile"; //sd card file name           
    try {
//Provide the id of raw file to the openRawResource() method
                  in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.brawler);
                  out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + filename);
                  copyFile(in, out);
                  in.close();
                  in = null;
                  out.flush();
                  out.close();
                  out = null;
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                }       

        }
        private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
              out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the raw resource input stream this way:

```
// in your activity in `onClick` event of the button:
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourResourceName);
```

Then read it to a buffer and write it to a file output stream:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("real/path/name"); // you'll need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for writing in external storage
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;
while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
  os.write(buffer, 0, size);
}
is.close();
os.close();
```